# MySQL timing out? Can't tell what's going on, Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, apache-commons-dbcp

i'm running this method to update an SQL using DBCP connection pooling:

After **exactly 8 times**, the method setValue stops doing so, and no data is sent.

```
    public static void setValue(String user, Integer id){
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        try {
            connection = DataSource.getInstance().getConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ttl++;
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("REPLACE INTO " + "accounts"+ " (user,id) VALUES(?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, user);
        ps.setInt(2, id);
        ps.executeUpdate();
                    ps.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return;
}
```

I am not familiar with MySQL or connection pooling, i do not know what is going wrong here. Please help me troubleshoot this or provide any suggestions? Thank you so much!

Comment: where are you closing your statement, possibly connection, and returning it to the pool?

Comment: I don't think i am..i wasn't sure how to handle statements with pooling.

Comment: Is your connection pool exactly 8 connections big?

Comment: Is your `Connection`'s autocommit disabled?

Comment: How would I set the size? I'm very new to connection pools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should be closing your connection, which will simply return it to the pool.  Basically you should add this in a finally {} block in your method.  Hope this helps.

```
public static void setValue(String user, Integer id){
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        try {
            connection = DataSource.getInstance().getConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ttl++;
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("REPLACE INTO " + "accounts"+ " (user,id) VALUES(?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, user);
        ps.setInt(2, id);
        ps.executeUpdate();
                    ps.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) connection.close();
    }    
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you are just using all the connections in your pool

try putting in a finally block

```
finally {
connection.close();
}
```

Even though you are using a connection pool you still have to close the connection - it's just that the connection pool doesn't actually close it, it just returns it to the pool so someone else can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a try catch finally block, commit your connection in the try, close your prepared statement in the finally, and on exception rollback.

```
 public static void setValue(String user, Integer id){
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        try {
            connection = DataSource.getInstance().getConnection();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ttl++;
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("REPLACE INTO " + "accounts"+ " (user,id) VALUES(?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, user);
        ps.setInt(2, id);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        connection.commit();           
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        connection.rollback();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        ps.close();
    }
    return;
}
```